# How to make a circular selection box using SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a school assignment which seems to be eating most of my nerves. I'm a newbie coder and I need to use HTML/CSS/Javascript in order to create a SVG editor.

My code is here:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLGBwR`

I managed to figure out some of it but now i'm stuck at this: How can I change the selection box shape from rectangle to circle? i.e: selecting and moving the cursor to the left will create a rectangle and now I need it to be a circle.

What should I use? Thanks!

```
 svg rect {
fill: gray;
fill-opacity: 0.2;
stroke: navy;
stroke-opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Comment: Please go plop your stuff into a codepen or a jsfiddle or something to make it easier for folks to help.

Comment: ok, link has been replaced with the codepen one.

Comment: Did you already try just swapping your `rect` instances with `ellipse`?

Comment: first thing i thought of. no, it's not working like that

Comment: Guess I'll actually have to go look then lol, sorry dude it's Friday so motivation levels are minimal but welcome to SO!

Comment: chillax! much appreciated though!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly John. Your code is unreadable.  You need to learn how to indent. It will save you a lot of misery. Trust me.

Secondly, since it is your homework, no-one is going to give you the solution outright. But I will give you a couple of hints.

The `<rect>` element has the attributes `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2`.  The `<circle>` element has the attributes `cx`, `cy` and `r`.  So obviously you can't do a straight swap of `<rect>` to `<circle>`.

Think about how you would drag out a circle.  Commonly the centre would be at the first point, and you would drag out the radius.

You don't have the radius. However you do have start and end points which you can calculate the radius from.  Use Pythagoras' theorem for that.

Good luck.

Comment: Hello Paul. I never said I needed a straightforward solution to this. I'd be more than happy to understand rather than use someone else's code. Now.. everything else you said has nothing to do with what I asked.